# Want to change my master to an older commit, how can I do this?

Tags: git

I want to rollback to a previous commit, and then publish that code, then go back to the latest commit.

i.e. so my master is pointing to an older commit version just so I can pulish that version, then I want to go back to the latest commit I was one initially.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 114):

If you want to do this and revert the master to the previous commit:

```
git checkout master~1            # Checkout previous commit on master
git checkout -b new_master       # Create branch for new master
git branch -D master             # Delete old master
git branch -mv new_master master # Make new_master master
```

Alternatively:

```
git reset --hard master~1        # Reset current branch to one commit ago on master
```

Comment: So a year later i'm looking at this and thinking this is an awful way to do it. Oh well at least it's somewhat easy to understand.

Comment: yes this is why I upvoted, easy to understand, maybe you should have presented a link to a better way?

Comment: I had to do the same using SourceTree. The process is similar.
1) create new branch for current master state, so you won't lose anything.
2) delete master
3) create new master branch, selecting the desired commit

Comment: What happens to the commit we "removed" from master after this?

Comment: It's still in your reflog. Nothing comitted is ever "removed" this just re-points your HEAD at another commit.

Comment: Just followed this advice and erased other uncommited changes that I forgot about. There seems to be no way to recover it :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788037/recover-from-git-reset-hard See safer commands are discussed there. They recommend unlearning `git reset` because it is too dangerous. Of course in some situations this is helpful, but it should be understood that some data might be erased.

Comment: This should be avoided if you have a remote repo. It causes some errors if you do, because the address of the first master differs from the new master you created recently.

Answer (score 108):

If you want to avoid force pushing, here's how to revert your repo to an older commit and preserve all intervening work:

```sh
git checkout 307a5cd        # check out the commit that you want to reset to 
git checkout -b fixy        # create a branch named fixy to do the work
git merge -s ours master    # merge master's history without changing any files
git checkout master         # switch back to master
git merge fixy              # and merge in the fixed branch
git push                    # done, no need to force push!
```

Done! Replace 307a5cd with whatever commit you want in your repo.

(I know the first two lines can be combined, but I think that makes it less clear what's going on)

Here it is graphically:

```
c1 -- c2 -- c3 -- c4 -- c2' -- c5 ...
        \              /
         '------------'
```

You effectively remove c3 and c4 and set your project back to c2. However, c3 and c4 are still available in your project's history if you ever want to see them again.

Comment: This worked without a hitch! If you have come down this far and are reading this -- this appears to be the cleanest way to revert master to a deeper commit.

Comment: I can not find the words to explain how much I love you for this, I am greatful beyond words for getting to fix something that had me bugged for 6h now and caused me so much headache. Thank you sir!!!!!!!

Comment: To anyone who is looking for a solid solution!

Comment: For anyone scratching their head over 'ours' mentioned above. Its a built-in git command.. https://howchoo.com/git/git-merge-conflicts-rebase-ours-theirs

Comment: @Blankman I suggest you make this the accepted answer it covers everything people are needing and it's safe unlike the current top answer.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for! Dear reader, this is the answer you should try.

Comment: A slightly safer way is to merge origin/master which is more likely to match the intention, especially if you're used to work (only) with feature branches and your local master may be out-of-date. Of course this requires that you have done git fetch

Comment: Your answer is a gem. It's hard to find your solution between all the other "reset" and "checkout" answers that will destroy the history.

Answer (score 75):

Your question is unclear. I *think* what you are asking for is this:

```
git push -f origin $old_commit_id:master
```

What will this do? It will push the `$old_commit_id` commit to `origin` as the new head of `origin`’s `master` branch.

If that is what you wanted, you do not need to touch your local `master` branch at all.

Comment: This caused a `master (non-fast-forward)` failure for me. @jtdubs solution worked.

Comment: Just pass `-f` to force it – though the remote repo may be configured to forbid that. I’ve updated the answer.

Comment: doesn't work for me, the accepted answer does though

Comment: You didn’t say exactly what you wanted or why it didn’t work so I can’t tell you why it didn’t and how it could have been made to (if it could have).

Comment: You do appear to lose past history on remote with this approach, was fine for me.  Just calling it out.

Comment: Yes. The question seemed to be how to unpublish some history, and that’s what this answer does, in the most direct way possible.

Comment: WHOA. Much simpler than all those reseting. Thanks!

Answer (score 52):

use `git reset --hard <old commit number>`

it will reset the HEAD to this old commit.

additionally, you need to use `git push -f origin` to alter the remote repo too.

Answer (score 10):

You can just `git checkout <commit-id>`, do whatever you need to do, then `git checkout master` to get back to the new code.

If you actually need to modify the old code to release it, then you should probably:

```
git checkout -b my_release <commit-id>
... prepare code for release ...
... release code ...
git checkout master
git merge my_release
```

Also, I can't recommend [git flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) enough.  It makes all of this quite easy.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming a commit graph like so:

```
| (A) ---------> (B) ----------> (C)
|                                 ^
|                              (master)
```

You want to first checkout `master` and create a branch that points to where `master` currently is:

```
git checkout master
git branch pointer master
```

Should look like this now:

```
| (A) ---------> (B) ----------> (C)
|                                 ^
|                       (HEAD, master, pointer)
```

Now that you're already on `master`, we'll tell the `master` branch to move backward one commit:

```
git reset master~1
```

Now, `master` should be moved back one space, but the `pointer` branch is still on the most recent commit :

```
| (A) ---------> (B) ----------> (C)
|                 ^               ^
|           (HEAD, master)    (pointer)
```

At this point, you can push `master` to a remote, or where ever, then fast forward merge it back up to the `pointer` branch. You can kill the `pointer` branch at that point :

```
git push origin master
git merge --ff-only pointer
git branch -D pointer
```

Final :

```
| (A) ---------> (B) ----------> (C)
|                 ^               ^
|         [ origin/master ]    (HEAD, master)
```

Comment: If origin/master is at C, `git push origin master` will fail with _the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart_. You should also pass a -f flag.

Answer (score 1):

To move to a previous version:

`git checkout <version hash>`

do your work here and commit it with

`git commit --amend`

To go back to **master**:

`git checkout master`

Comment: That won't work.  `git reset --hard` pointed his master branch back to the old commit, so `git checkout master` will do nothing.

Comment: True, thanks for the correction. +1 to you, would remove my answer too but I think the `commit --amend` step is useful enough

Comment: What's `--amend` ?

Answer (score 0):

checkout to your old commit:

```
git reset --hard <your old commit>
```

create a new branch:

```
git checkout -b BugfixingV1
```

now merge it with the master branch and keep your changes by conflicts:

```
git merge -s ours master
```

Now our new Branch is ready to be our new master branch, so let's switch again to the master branch:

```
git checkout master
```

and now we need to merge the new branch into the master!

```
git merge BugfixingV1
```

Finally, we'll push the the changes into the Repository:

```
git push
```