# anyway to roll back working directory after git rm -r -f

Tags: git, git-rm

I think I might have screwed my days work but I did this chain of commands

```
git status
git add .
git rm filename1
git rm filename2
```

I then stupidly thought why am I doing this one by one I know there is a way to do it all at once

```
git rm -r -f
```

working directory gets wiped I realised I have messed up and then tried

```
git checkout -f
```

which restored everything to my last commit which was this morning.

I am looking at these answers and thinking there might be a way but I dont understand those answers well enough to risk trying anything yet, any advice?

[Can a “git rm -r -f ” command be reverted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078781/can-a-git-rm-r-f-directory-command-be-reverted)

[How to undo a “ git rm -r -f * ”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17771679/how-to-undo-a-git-rm-r-f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the linked answers, everything that you added to index with `git add` should be possible to recover with:

```
git fsck --lost-found
```

This will create the files that you added to the index but never committed in the `.git/lost-found/other` directory. The filenames will be SHAs instead, so you will have to look inside one by one to know which is which.

Comment: Thank-you for pointing that out that was my best chance and they are indeed there in the other folder now.  I am delighted that git is smarter than me.  Do you know how to restore those files or should i just copy and paste them do you think?

Comment: @Ir1sh I think you'll have to copy and paste. I didn't know this feature btw, so I'm glad at your question ;-)