# How to revert changes after git reset

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recover from git reset --hard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788037/recover-from-git-reset-hard)

I first used `git add .`, but it added some files I don't want to include in the repository.

So I ran `git reset --hard HEAD` before committing the changes. Is there a way to get these changes back?

Comment: Not an obvious one that I know unfortunately - for future reference, use `git reset <paths>` for this rather than `git reset --hard HEAD`, since the latter basically nukes your changes and resets your working copy to HEAD. See the man page here: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5788037/422353

Comment: Not quite a dupe of what madth3 has (that question doesnt mention adding to the index before resetting) but an answer in that link does apply to your question

http://stackoverflow.com/a/6780036/496405

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't. That's why I always recommend to use

```
git stash -u
```

to get the same effect but you can undo that action.