# Recover staged but not committed files after 'git rm -rf'

Tags: git, git-rm, git-fsck

On my local machine I removed files from folder.

```
git init
git add --all
```

then I wrote (don't ask me, why! :) )

```
git rm -rf
```

I don't commit, yet. Now I have empty folders in my project. In `.git` folder has `objects` with 53 Mb of files.

How can I recover my files? I've tried programs like Drill Disc and Stellar, but not found my files. And I can't rollback from GIT.

How can I recover the lost files?

Comment: If you do not get them back by using any "undelete" tool, they are gone.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788037/recover-from-git-reset-hard/6780036#6780036 this may be useful

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**(update)** Use `git fsck` instead, it is a builtin command for retrieving files you have once added to git repository.

```
git fsck --lost-found --unreachable
```

after the command processing, retrieved files will be placed at `.git/lost-found/other`, with file name of a sha256 hash. Although the original name is still lost, the content will be back.

---

You can find your files in your `.git/objects` directory.

Suppose there is a `.git/objects/2f/ae996f8f8f9298b41ba4fdbac3d62014f9579e` object, you can execute

```
git cat-file -p 2fae996
```

to get the content of your lost file.

But I'm sorry, I have no idea about reconstructing your directory or doing this automatically.

Comment: +1: Wow, indeed. Strange that the files are there but are not accessible in any way using the normal git commands.

Comment: Im not worry about directories, but I need files. 
"git cat-file" - this like "cat" command in *nix? 

How can I save file in other directory?

Comment: you can save it by redirection just like an usual unix command. `git cat-file object > /path/to/where/you/want/save/it`, but I think it is not a really good idea because there is no information about file names.

Comment: It possible to do it automaticly!

Here is my shit-code on PHP )) http://codepad.org/khIjLFnI

Comment: @DanielHilgarth `git show 2fae996` can do it too (how shame I don't know it until today), `show` is a versatile upper interface for many lower command.

Comment: Thank you so much, I thought I'd lost all my files :)

Answer (score -2):

have you tried :

```
git reset --hard
```

?

Hope that works :)

Comment: After a `git rm -rf`, you can even safely do a hard reset.

Comment: -1: That would only work if `rm -rf` would have been used. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14475121/572644) for an explanation.

Comment: This command changed the code to the last commit and remove all the modified files.

Comment: You really should delete this answer. It doesn't help *at all*.

Comment: I did almost the exact same thing as the person who asked the question. The only difference is that I was a lot further along on a project. This answer resolved the issue for me.  I lost all of the work I'd done since my last commit, and I learned my lesson about trying to use shortcuts when I need to stage deleted files, but at least I didn't lose the whole project.  Thanks!