# Can I retrieve a file in git that had been created, staged, never committed, but then removed?

Tags: git

I created a file then staged it in my git repo using `git add <file>`.

I also wanted to remove some files in the same commit so did a `git rm -f 'files.*'`.

The wildcard I used in the remove line was a little too generic, and it removed my previously staged file.

Bearing in mind it was never committed, only staged, is there any way of retrieving the file I inadvertently removed?

Comment: Try `git checkout file`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recover files after 'git rm -rf'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475003/recover-files-after-git-rm-rf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had staged a file to git, you likely get it back;

1. Try `git fsck --lost-found`

The output will be something like;

```
$ git fsck --lost-found
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
dangling blob 20d25014d965f1fe519d53204222369d09503511
dangling blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391
```

2. One of the `dangling blob` should be your file. Try `git show <sha>` to see the file.

Note: Do **NOT** run `git gc` before the above steps. It cleans up unnecessary files and optimize the local repository.