# Undo git rm -f [file]

Tags: git, git-rm

I accidentally removed 3 files from both git and my working directory with

```
git rm -f [file]
```

when I was only trying to get git to ignore them. Is there any way to undo this command? The files have been changed since my last commit.

Comment: The only sure pathway back to a previous state is to go to a commit. If there were none, you can't. Sorry for your loss.

Comment: Unless you have some other backup, then the changes you made to those files are lost.  `git rm` won't normally remove files that have been changed, but the `-f` option overrides that.

Comment: Also this may be the answer for what you were trying to do (ignore changes to files that are being tracked): http://stackoverflow.com/a/17410119/12711

Comment: I see. I had a feeling that'd be the case, but I wanted to make absolutely sure. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to revert a "git rm -r ."?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125710/how-to-revert-a-git-rm-r)

Comment: possible solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475003/recover-files-after-git-rm-rf

Answer (score 0):

Since you used `-f`, there should be no way in git to get them back.
But: if you didn't yet reset the files to a former version, there's a good chance that the actual **data still resides on your hard disk**.

You can use a software that scans your drive for deleted but recoverable files.
There should be some of those programs for each major OS. On Windows I successfully used [Undelete360](http://www.undelete360.com/download.html) but there are also other options.