# recover file after git rm with no previous history

Tags: git, git-rm

Not sure there´s a solution to this:

I accidentally staged a directory with:

```
git add *
```

then, upon seeing this, I did (major, major mistake, should have of course unstaged)

```
git rm -r my_directory
```

To top it all, I followed up with:

```
git commit -m ¨horrible commit¨
```

Now the files are nowhere to be found. Is there a way to recover the files?

Thanks

Comment: Related. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475003/recover-staged-but-not-commited-files-after-git-rm-rf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the git rm shouldn't have deleted this directory but complained:

```
error: the following file has changes staged in the index: my_directory
(use --cached to keep the file, or -f to force removal)
```

So the directory should still be there...

If you ran it with -f, sorry, then I guess there's nothing you can do.

Comment: Ah! indeed, thanks for your message. That indicated me that I had actually committed a previous version with the directory in there, that´s why it did not complain!