# in git, can i restore previous uncommitted index state?

Tags: git, indexing

I had modified some files and staged them (they were added to index).  Then i mistakenly called `git reset --hard`.  Is it possible to restore the state of the index from before the reset?  In other words, i'm looking for something like `reflog` for index, which would allow me to browse previous states of the index, even uncommitted ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6780036/2058424), which partially answers my question, and helps recovering lost files: you can use `git fsck --lost-found`, which will save unreferenced objects to `<path to repo>/.git/lost-found/`, and staged-but-uncommitted changes were there.

I'm not sure if this doesn't qualify this question to be marked as duplicate, though.