# How to recover last commit after git hard reset?

Tags: git

Can I recover the following commit after a hard reset?

Steps:

```
1) $ (master) // ....made a bunch of changes to files thinking I was working on a branch
2) $ git checkout -b 001-branch  // copy changes to a branch to work with
3) $ (001-branch) // make some more changes to files
4) $ (001-branch) git commit -a -m 'added and changed stuff'
// at this point I was just going to pull force master to latest then rebase my 001-branch off of original master (not the stuff I had modified)
5) $ (001-branch) git checkout master
6) $ (master) git reset --hard HEAD
7) $ (master) git pull
8) $ (master) git checkout 001-branch // go back to my branch and rebase my changes
9) $ (001-branch) // oops...my changes were all kiboshed and I don't see the commit I did per git lg
```

Any way out of this mess to recover my changes?

Comment: A few questions: (1) Was the commit in step 4 actually successful? (2) Did you actually do a rebase at step 8 or not yet? (3) What does "all kiboshed" mean? Do you see the commit made in step 4 at all, is it mangled in some way, or is it just missing? (4) Do you see your commit in `git reflog` on 001-branch? The reflog is the usual way to dig yourself out of this sort of thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recover from git reset --hard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788037/recover-from-git-reset-hard)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To see all the changes made to your 001-branch, you can do `git reflog 001-branch`, however, chances are what you think you did in 001-branch maybe you did another branch, so you probably need to look into all the changes with `git reflog`.

Answer (score 21):

Does `git reflog show` print the hash of the missing commit? If yes, then `git checkout -b recovery-branch commitId` will create a new branch pointing to the missing commit. You can then merge as needed.

Answer (score 7):

Every time git does something drastic like changing or rewinding branches, it records that in reflog. In other words, carefully inspect output of `git reflog`, it will tell you all transitions you branch ever had. You can then use `git show commit_id` to inspect and `git checkout commit_id` to get back.

Answer (score 4):

Honestly I don't get what happened.

`git reflog` prints what commits a branch *was pointing at*.
You can use it to find the SHA1 sum of recent *local* commits.

Comment: And can I restore that commit to my main history?