# All files/folders were gone when I runned this command in Git

Tags: git, git-reset

by running this command my all files/folder consisting git init are gone.I run this command in my ubuntu terminal
**git reset --hard origin/master**
and following was the response obtained 
**HEAD is now at 979997c Initial commit**
but when I run git log only the initial commit with 979997c commit id is visible

I am in tension whether all my files are gone...Is there any way to get back all the files.. Please help..Please help me out of this since all the projects I did are in this folder

Comment: As a side note, it's probably best if you have an individual repository for each project as opposed to keeping all of them in one repository

Comment: I had one workspace followed by different projects!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to recover last commit after git hard reset?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19898557/how-to-recover-last-commit-after-git-hard-reset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `git reflog` and find the commit before you reset to 979997c.

Say that commit has id 1234567, run `git log 1234567` to verify it's correct, and then re-reset the branch with `git reset --hard 1234567`.

Comment: You'll also see each action has HEAD@{x}.  You can also use git reset --hard HEAD@{x}

Comment: You're welcome. In the future be careful not to run commands that you're not sure what they're going to do.