# Accidentally deleted files in git using reset --hard before committing

Tags: git, github

I was trying to initialize git on one of my projects. I added all my files / folders to the staging area using `git add *`. I then committed a readme file, and then pushed it to remote repo. Then I committed 1 folder using `git commit folder/*` and then did another push.

But after that, I did a `git reset --hard`. Now all my files from the last few weeks are gone (I did not keep a backup of the project either), and I only have the readme file. Is there any way to recover the deleted files?

I tried getting the blob files using `git fsck –lost-found`, and restored them using `git show -p --format=raw $blob > $blob.txt`. But this gives me around 3000 blob files. How can I go through all these files to get the latest ones? Moreover, the filenames are random. Do I need to go through all 3000 files, match the appropriate files, and find out the latest version manually?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recover from git reset --hard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788037/recover-from-git-reset-hard)

Comment: For future readers: the best advice is to add and commit your work several times a day, and push to a remote server at least daily. This note comes too late for the OP, but for users switching to a distributed version control system, the above is essential.

Answer (score 0):

Try reverting back to the commit in which *"Then I committed 1 folder using "git commit folder/" and then did another push"*

For that first do a 
    `git log`
Then identify the commit hash you want to revert to (say afb465c)
Next 
    `git revert afb465c`
Hopefully, this will take your repo to the state just before the reset.

Comment: Would that restore files which were added but not committed?

Comment: I am afraid not. `git revert` always take your repo to the state of that commit.

Comment: That's the problem. I never committed the files, just added them. So reverting to a previous version would not work.

Comment: Oh. Then I don't think git would be of much help. You can try some data recovering software like Recuva or Restoration. They might work if you haven't fiddled around too much.