# How do I change the push desitnation of my github repository?

Tags: github

I tried to go back to a previous commit and start my project over, but I was always running into errors and it has been a whole day of mispent time.

Backstory here: [Trying to go back to previous commits in Github while accidently uploading another repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76981288/trying-to-go-back-to-previous-commits-in-github-while-accidently-uploading-anoth?noredirect=1#comment135708264_76981288)

So I finally decided to grab the most recent file and download the zip files. After doing that, I deleted the repository and created a new one and uploaded the files. When I attempt to do so I run git status and I get this output. I have attempted to do command shift p . to see the hidden files but I have been unable to do so.
When I type in git add . I git this monster list of outputs. Is there a way to unstage them all at once or do I have to go in line by line? How did these ../ entries get there?

I was running git add . but that was from my project folder. How did these other files get into the staging area? I have run git reset and I have NOT made any commits to the github repository yet.

```
`37 files changed, 797 insertions(+)
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/.gitignore
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/.vscode/settings.json
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/README.MD
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/accounts/init.py
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/accounts/admin.py
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/accounts/apps.py
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/accounts/forms.py
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/accounts/migrations/0001_initial.py
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/accounts/migrations/init.py
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/accounts/models.py
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/accounts/tests.py
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/accounts/urls.py
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/accounts/views.py
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/django_project/init.py
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/django_project/asgi.py
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/django_project/settings.py
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/django_project/urls.py
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/django_project/wsgi.py
create mode 100755 Desktop/news/manage.py
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/pages/init.py
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/pages/admin.py
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/pages/apps.py
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/pages/migrations/init.py
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/pages/models.py
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/pages/tests.py
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/pages/urls.py
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/pages/views.py
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/templates/base.html
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/templates/home.html
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/templates/registration/login.html
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/templates/registration/password_change_done.html
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/templates/registration/password_change_form.html
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/templates/registration/password_reset_complete.html
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/templates/registration/password_reset_confirm.html
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/templates/registration/password_reset_done.html
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/templates/registration/password_reset_form.html
create mode 100644 Desktop/news/templates/registration/signup.html
(base) andrewstribling@Andrews-MBP news % git add .
(base) andrewstribling@Andrews-MBP news % git commit -m "chapter 12"
On branch main
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 1 commit.
(use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Untracked files:
../../.CFUserTextEncoding
../../.DS_Store
../../.Trash/
../../.anaconda/
../../.bash_history
../../.bash_profile
../../.bashrc.save
../../.conda/
../../.condarc
../../.config/
../../.continuum/
../../.cups/
../../.docker/
../../.fly/
../../.gitconfig
../../.idlerc/
../../.ipynb_checkpoints/
../../.ipython/
../../.jupyter/
../../.lesshst
../../.matplotlib/
../../.mono/
../../.npm/
../../.pgadmin/
../../.psql_history
../../.python_history
../../.ssh/
../../.tcshrc
../../.viminfo
../../.vscode/argv.json
../../.vscode/cli/
../../.vscode/extensions/
../../.xonshrc
../../.zprofile
../../.zsh_history
../../.zsh_sessions/
../../.zshrc
../../Andrews_First_Jupyter_Notebook.ipynb
../../Applications/
../../Baseball_Databank/
../../Codecademy_Resturant.sql
../../DJANGO_Meetup/
../.DS_Store
../.localized
../.ssh:config
../6 Popular Data Analytics Certifications_ Your 2023 Guide _ Coursera_files/
../Andrew Stribling Pathways.docx
../Codecademy learn Data analyst. copy.pdf
../ID THEFT AFFIDAVIT FTC.pdf
../Programming/
../Screen Shot 2023-08-21 at 10.49.51 PM.png
../convert_csv/
../keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf
../kobe-angry-949098398.jpg
../../Django_Tutorial_Polls_App
../../Documents/
../../Downloads/
../../Library/
../../Movies/
../../Music/
../../Pictures/
../../Pipfile
../../Pipfile.lock
../../Public/
../../Untitled.ipynb
../../anaconda3/
../../andrew-board/
../../django_for_beginners/
../../djangodelights/
../../get-pip.py
../../gitignore
../../jupyter.py
../../mysite/
../../placeholder.py
../../project_env/
../../python.py
../../untitled.txt
../../venv/
../../welcome-to-docker/`
```

What did I try and what am I expecting?

I want to be able to add files wihtout the ../.

I want to be able to start a new repository.

What have I done to solve the problem?

I have checked Codecademy material to see if they teach it.

I asked a question in the Github forums.

I checked the github documentation for commands to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you accidentally ran `git init` in your home folder (`/Users/something`), and now your entire home dir is tracked.

To solve this without losing all of your history you'll have to try something like

```
cd ~/Desktop/news
mv ~/.git .
git add -A .
git commit -m 'move .git from $HOME, restore paths in repo'
```

But you're in a bit of a messy spot so the specifics will vary.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

While there may be many ways to solving this problem. The way that I managed to stop all of those files being loaded was to add .git to my git ignore file.

It seems I was committing under the wrong folder which led to my github repostiory changing targets. Once I reset all of my commits and moved into project folder with pwd I was able to git add . and git push. git fetch was helpful as well.