# How to undo all git commits done today?

Tags: git

By mistake I have reset hard by using following command :

```
git reset --hard HEAD~
```

Now I want to undo all commits and the affect which git reset have made,and want to goto where I started today, Can I do that?

Comment: Find the last commit of yesterday, and do `git reset --hard <last commit of yesterday>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recover from git reset --hard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788037/recover-from-git-reset-hard)

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40939503/5358968) might be of particular use with `git-reflog`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git reset` does not create commits.

The best bet for undoing a `git reset` is to do another `git reset`, using the reflog.

```
git reflog
```

should show a list of where `HEAD` has recently been (in the local repository).  Hopefully one of those entries will be "where you started today".  In the case where the reset is all you did, this will be identified as `HEAD@{1}`, so you would then do

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```