# How can I recover from git reset --hard?

Tags: git

I was working on my code project that uses git that I don't really understand too much. I thought if I hard reset my head I would have only the last work. Now I have found out that I have lost my work after doing `git reset --hard HEAD`. Maybe I had all my work on git add status and when I did the command everything is gone. I tried a lot to look for a solution but didn't understand any one of it, and I'm worrying if I do something it will make it worse.

How can I recover from that problem?

I did `git log` in the first and I had 2 now I have only one one after I did my mistake.
As you can see now I have only one:

[image]

I remember that the name was `"initial commit"` instead of v1. When I do `reflog` I still can see it. Is there any way to fix that and bring back this work please?

[image]

Comment: Solved it git reset --hard 0606617 was the solution to bring it back

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recover from git reset --hard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788037/recover-from-git-reset-hard)

Comment: Step 1 - do not panic. Step 2 - learn about reachability in git. Step 3 - realise the issue is not an issue and use the reflog to "recover".

Comment: i.e. use `git reset --hard 9eeac25`

Comment: Sorry I paniced