# Lost data that I didn't commit after git pull

Tags: git, gitkraken

I work in a small group , so I wanted to make a new commit (for the new classes I did ) and then push but before that I did pull all the work of my friends , once it worked after many attempts (at first i got a error message but I don't know what I did but it worked), Now I wanted to commit and push but I couldn't found my classes.

Check [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OrH1.png)

I work with gitKraken .So I did the pull from "Tex datei nur mit dem wichtigsten" (2 days ago)

How can I get my classes back? Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Did you commit your changes before you pull your friend's work?

Comment: I don't know about GitKraken, but git normally warns you before pulling from remote to stash or commit your local changes. Did you do either of them? There's a "WIP on master: Auto stash" from the image.

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman no i did not commit my chages .

Comment: @GinoMempin that "WIP on master: Auto stash" doesn't contain my classes

Comment: If you didn't commit or stash your local changes before the pull, then they're most likely already gone/overwritten. Plus, there are already a lot of commits between pulling "Tex datei nur mit dem wichtigsten" and "nix geandert" (which I assume is where you're at)

Comment: @GinoMempin so there is no way to recover my classes ??

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5788069/2745495. But basically, if you didn't commit or stash (or even stage) anything, then there is no way to recover them.

Comment: I don't know any way to recover any un-stashed or un-committed changes. :(

Comment: Gitkraken has done this since day one for me, its auto-stash/unstash feature when pulling is dodgy at best and never was reliable for me. SourceTree has its issues and looks less funky, but is more reliable and faster for me.