# Github Retrieve the code after I make a mistake

Tags: git, fetch, push, pull

I just make a mistake at the time of working in a Java project. The code was in the IntelliJ and I make a repo in the Github with the intention to push there. I initially tried to push and I get information that the branch was behind. I think its due to the reason I put the LICENSE and the .gitignore in the repo at the time of creation.

I perform the commands then,

```
$ git fetch --all
$ git reset --hard origin/master
```

The IDEA has node code and all gone.

[image]

The log info is here:

```
$ git log 
commit b6e96685f6c0d4e77ac39e45499fc0213808cdb5 (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
Author: Chaklader <omi.chaklader@gmail.com>
Date:   Sat Feb 9 11:04:31 2019 +0100

    updated

commit 1572b11db8f42f5444df312f5f86c5791befb22c
```

How do I get back to the previous commit now? I have done nothing afterward.

Update:

I did little mess with check out the branches and stash them. Afterward, I perform the following operations as suggested.

```
$ git reset --hard
$ git clean -fdx

$ git checkout master # make sure you are on the right branch first
$ git reset --hard HEAD@{1}

$ git pull --rebase
```

I find no changes and the IDE look like the following,

[image]

The log is here:

```
$ git log

$ git log
commit b6e96685f6c0d4e77ac39e45499fc0213808cdb5 (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
Author: Chaklader <omi.chaklader@gmail.com>
Date:   Sat Feb 9 11:04:31 2019 +0100

    updated

commit 1572b11db8f42f5444df312f5f86c5791befb22c
```

I'm in the master branch now:

```
$ git branch 
* master
```

When I did stash, I get the info,

```
$ git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: b6e9668 updated
```

The `reflog` command provides the info,

```
    $ git reflog show
1572b11 (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to 1572b11db8f
1572b11 (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to 1572b11db8f
b6e9668 (origin/master) HEAD@{2}: reset: moving to HEAD
b6e9668 (origin/master) HEAD@{3}: reset: moving to HEAD
b6e9668 (origin/master) HEAD@{4}: reset: moving to HEAD@{1}
b6e9668 (origin/master) HEAD@{5}: reset: moving to HEAD@{1}
b6e9668 (origin/master) HEAD@{6}: checkout: moving from master to master
:
```

The command `$ git reset --hard 1572b11db8f` return almost no code page,

[image]

Is there a possibility that I lost the code forever? Please, kindly help me.

Comment: If you worked on that in IDEA you can probably recover your code from [Local History](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html), that's unrelated to version-control.

Comment: On the VCS menu, point to Local History, and then click Show History. It shows nothing for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you had done a commit before your `reset --hard`, try now:

```
git checkout master # make sure you are on the right branch first
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

Check [`git reflog` as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24236065/6309) to determine the right reference to reset to (`git reflog show)`.

Then

```
git pull --rebase
```

Finally

```
git push
```

---

If `git relog` does not show any relevant commit, then you need to use some file-saving feature of your environment:

- IntelliJ IDEA [Local History](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html)
- [Time Capsule/Time Machine](https://www.macworld.com/article/3311980/networking/switch-away-from-time-capsule-to-time-machine-volumes.html) on Mac
- [File recovery tools](https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/top-5-data-recovery-software-mac.html)
- ...

Comment: I was trying to get a fix quickly and I have done `git checkout b6e96685f6c0d4e77ac39e45499fc0213808cdb5 ` and `git stash` onto them. Your command doesn't help now. Please, kindly tell me what to do.

Comment: @Arefe Is b6e96685f the right commit? (the one you had before your first reset?). If yes: `git checkout master; git reset --hard b6e96685f`

Comment: I wasn't able to check out the master . I get the output `$ git checkout master
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        .idea/vcs.xml
        .idea/workspace.xml
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting`

Comment: @Arefe Again, if you have the right commit, do a `git reset --hard`, `git clean -fdx` to reset everything, then checkout master, reset to the right commit, pull rebase.

Comment: Please, see the updated question. I find no change till now. I get very nervous at the moment.

Comment: @Arefe Again: did you make a commit *before* trying your initial push? If yes, that commit, and its content, is not lost: check the output of `git reflog show`: in your case, try a `git reset --hard 1572b11db8f` to see if you get your old code back. (and then: pull --rebase, and push)

Comment: I did make a commit before the initial push. It's great to know. I provided the output for the `reflog` in the updated answer.

Comment: @Arefe OK. If you are on the master branch, a `git reset --hard 1572b11db8f` should show you your previous code.

Comment: @Arefe Is there any other commit beside b6e9668 `git reflog show`?

Comment: The `git reset --hard 1572b11db8f` shows nothing and I'm in the master branch.

Comment: I was not been able to perform the `pull --rebase` and get this, `$ git pull --rebase
Updating 1572b11..b6e9668
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
        .idea/vcs.xml
        .idea/workspace.xml
Please move or remove them before you merge.
Aborting
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        .idea/vcs.xml
        .idea/workspace.xml
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
could not detach HEAD`

Comment: You should do the `pull --rebase` only *after* having recovered your code. Not before. Make sure `git status` shows the rebase is not still in progress.

Comment: I will be back in an hour

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188140/discussion-between-vonc-and-arefe).