# git reset --hard will make source code lost permanently when the file is added to the staging zone but not in repository

Tags: git, git-reset

I add some new files to index

```
git add .
```

then reset

```
git reset --hard
```

git deleted these files in my working tree, there are not in repository previously, they are all lost. I lost all my data.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5788069/6330106. You can still find the contents of the added files. But the directory structure and filenames are lost.

Comment: Do you have a question? If you wanted to keep uncommitted things, why did you hard reset?

Comment: I want undo add. but keep the files in working tree. I run a wrong command, I should use --mixed @jonrsharpe

Comment: @yuanjianpeng Yes, and since `--mixed` is implied, `git reset` would be enough. Losing data is indeed frustrating in the short term, but sometimes you have to burn your hand once to learn a lesson...

Comment: If there is a small chance you might need to recover the contents of your worktree, you could use `git stash` instead of `git reset --hard HEAD`. This would similarly remove all changes to tracked files in your index/worktree, but it keeps those changes in the stash. Only run `git reset --hard HEAD` if you are really really sure that you will not need the changes you are about to discard.

Answer (score 1):

from the git documentation:

> --hard Resets the index and working tree. Any changes to tracked files in the working tree since  are **discarded**.

so this works exactly as documented. You probably wanted to do

```
git reset
```

without the `--hard` option.

See [Recover from git reset --hard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788037/recover-from-git-reset-hard) if you want to try to recover your code.