# Accidentally deleted my project from my computer

Tags: git

I'm completely new to Git.  It's been a week since I made my first commit and I had a hard week completing my React project.

I tried to push my code again but I ran into some problems. I tried solving them using `git reset --hard refs/original/refs/heads/master`, but I'm not even sure that was the right one; I tried so many of them. Now I'm surprised my project had been deleted and I'm having only the files that I previously committed to my repo.  What do I do?

Comment: If you really did a hard reset, then all the work which was is your working directory and stage may be lost.  If you are using a powerful IDE such as IntelliJ, then you may try using the local history to recover the changes to the files.

Comment: I'm only using vs code is there an option like finding in recycle bin or so. I'm really feeling sick right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saved my life use:

`git reflog show`

then choose the right Head, the one that corresponds to the desired commit message say for example `HEAD@{3}` finally run this `git reset HEAD@{3}` this is how I saved my life

more answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788037/recover-from-git-reset-hard)

Comment: Glad you found a solution - it'd be simplest to close this question out as a dupe.