# Accident with "git reset hard"

Tags: git, version-control, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

When I was coding one project this morning, I accidentally use "git reset hard" to reset my commits. As I had a lookup on SO and tried some recovery option. It brought me to this step. I need to get back to the commit "2070cc5 HEAD@{9}" but truly don't know how. [What my terminal displays:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOAwz.png)

Comment: Did you try `git checkout HEAD@{9}`?

Comment: Already answerd here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788037/recover-from-git-reset-hard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.make sure you working directory clean
2.if it's not clean, you can use execute `git stash` command to make it clean
3.execute `git reset --hard 2070cc5`, that's what you want
4.you might need to execute `git stash pop` to get the previous changes in working directory