# How to reset git back to what I have pushed

Tags: git, git-commit

I have did a checkout and the crontab did an entry in one file. I have commited the changes withouth push. Now I want to go back to the last comit before the checkout. Anyone knows how exactly to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`git reset --hard origin/master`

This assumes your remote repo has the default local ref `origin`, and you are on the master branch. To check this you can run `git branch -r` and you should see something like `origin/HEAD -> origin/master` as one row in the result.

As the comments rightly point out, the `--hard` option is going to irrevocably remove any local changes. Be sure this is what you want to do.

Comment: Be VERY careful of using `reset --hard` it is difficult recover from this if you loose information

Comment: HEAD is now at 1ffbdf0 commit to checkout. I did commit I did not stash the changes. Yes on origin/master

Comment: [This difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5788069/542251) @Robert-Dan

Comment: On the Git server the data is still there right?

Comment: Not if you didn't push it no

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "Git server the data "

Comment: I did pull but is the same last commit

Comment: "fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born"

Comment: suggests there are no commits on your branch, ie master has no initial commit. Maybe.

Comment: I was lucky that there was still the hashes on the Terminal at the last changes (commits). It was enough to write: git reset --hard 3aabb82