# Folder destroyed while cloning a git repo

Tags: git, recover

I was cloning my git repo (which was empty). As it was empty, I didn't notice it didn't finish cloning yet and I added files/folders to it, but it got destroyed before the cloning finished, and all my files/folders disappeared, is there any way to recover them please ?

Thank you

Comment: If they were not added or committed, then your best bet is to use your IDE's file history.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recover from losing uncommitted changes by "git reset --hard"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788037/recover-from-losing-uncommitted-changes-by-git-reset-hard)

Comment: When I do ```git fsck --lost-found``` I get this: 
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
notice: HEAD points to an unborn branch (master)
notice: No default references

I indeed had 256 files, but idk how to get them back from here

Comment: you can read the content of the files with blob but the name of the file will be lost. git show <id of blob> will output you the content of file.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I found one of the many folders I tried to commit had a commit in it so I could resolve it.