# GIT want to set my old version as my master

Tags: git, git-merge, tortoisegit

Currently, I have 1,2,3(master) version, however, in version 2, some file has been deleted. Now I would like to revert back to version 1, and set it as my master which is version 4.

I try checkout to version 1, and create a branch. and then I switch back to master, and merge the version 1 branch. It seem like version 3 still the master.

How can I set version 4 as version 1?
Totally out of idea to do it.

Looking solution for TortiseGIT if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open Log Message dialog, right click on first commit, perform `Compare with working tree`

[image]

2. TortoiseGit shows you the `Changed Files` dialog, select all files in the list, right click them, perform `Revert to revision`.

[image]

3. Commit the reverted files, and the log

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you by version mean commit then returning one commit back can be done like this: `git reset --hard master~1` although it seems to be an ugly hack.
I found this solution in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25574382/4751720), you should check it out as I think you will find solution there.