# Rollback git main branch prior to feature branch merge, do some work and merge the feature branch back again

Tags: git

The `main` branch includes commits from a feature branch `feature-A`. I want to revert `main` branch to the commit before the feature branch code change was merged and deploy this code for testing. Let's say that during testing multiple bugs are reported and I push commits to `main` to fix the bug. When the main branch does not have any more bugs, I then want to re-merge the code changes from feature branch `feature-A` back into `main`.

Note: `main` is protected, so a pull request is needed to apply new changes.

Example:

```
(main) 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5
```

Commits 3, 4, 5 includes `feature-A`

Now rollback main, so it becomes:

```
(main) 1 - 2
```

Apply bug fixes as part of commits 6 and 7

```
(main) 1 - 2 - 6 - 7
```

Now merge `feature-A` back to latest state of `main`

```
final state - (main) 1 - 2 - 6 - 7 - 3 - 4 - 5
```

What I have tried:
I first created a backup of my main branch and called it `main-backup`

From this post: [Want to change my master to an older commit, how can I do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359681/want-to-change-my-master-to-an-older-commit-how-can-i-do-this) I tried the below which gives me a new branch prior to `feature-A` which can be merged to main.

```
If you want to avoid force pushing, here's how to revert your repo to an older commit and preserve all intervening work:

git checkout 307a5cd        # check out the commit that you want to reset to 
git checkout -b fixy        # create a branch named fixy to do the work
git merge -s ours master    # merge master's history without changing any files
git checkout master         # switch back to master
git merge fixy              # and merge in the fixed branch
git push                    # done, no need to force push!
Done! Replace 307a5cd with whatever commit you want in your repo.

(I know the first two lines can be combined, but I think that makes it less clear what's going on)

Here it is graphically:

c1 -- c2 -- c3 -- c4 -- c2' -- c5 ...
        \              /
         '------------'
You effectively remove c3 and c4 and set your project back to c2. However, c3 and c4 are still available in your project's history if you ever want to see them again.
```

So I create the PR and merge. Now `main` is at the commit before `feature-A`.

Now if I create a PR to merge `main-backup` into `main` it should show me all the code commits/changes related to `feature-A` but GitHub says there are no code changes.

So my understanding is not right here.
What is the best (and possibly the safest) way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I dive into the answer, I need to address this part, because I have to draw some diagrams and I like to draw correct and unambiguous ones:

> Example:
>
> ```
> (main) 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5
> ```

Here, you have drawn a repository containing five commits total, all on a branch named `main`.  There are a couple of issues I have with this particular drawing.  One is quite minor, but might cause confusion later.  The other is also minor but important.

The first is that while Git commits *are* numbered, they don't have simple sequential *counting* numbers.  Their actual numbers are enormous (up to 2<sup>160</sup>-1 at the moment, and in the future, even bigger) and look random.  As a result I think it's better to use letter codes for the commits: here I'd use `A` through `E`, or `F` through `J`, or some such.

The second issue—important, though still minor—is that a *branch name* like `main` isn't a label you should stick *in front of* commits.  It's a label you should paste on *one single* commit, in this case, commit #5 or—as I will call it—commit `E`:

```
               main
                 |
                 v

 A <-B <-C <-D <-E
```

Note how each commit then points *backwards* to the *previous* commit.

For a somewhat more compact representation, I tend to use this:

```
A--B--C--D--E   <-- main
```

on StackOverflow.  This drops the internal arrows (which isn't great, but is barely tolerable as we'll see).

The reason to draw them like this is that a *branch name* really does point to *exactly one commit*.  That's the first crucial item to understanding what we can do with your existing repository and its commits.  And, each commit in a chain of commits like this really does point backwards to the previous commit.

More precisely, the commits are, as we noted earlier, numbered.  The actual numbers—expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)—look bizarre and random, like <sub><sup>`f6b272b0c674c2d5022e90c3dec868af4ea26522`</sup></sub> for instance.  They're too difficult for humans to bother with.  That's why we have the *computer* remember the *last one in a chain* using a branch name like `main`.

Each commit contains two things:

- A commit has a full snapshot of every file.  The files stored inside each commit are stored in a special, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated format.  This is something your computer cannot read in general; only *Git* can read these files.  So you don't actually *use* these files: they are stored only for history purposes.  They act like a permanent archive, like a zip or tar archive of every file.
- And, each commit contains some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  This includes the name of the person who made the commit, their email address, and a date-and-time stamp, for instance.  But it also includes the raw hash ID of the *earlier* commit.  Hence, commit `E`, whatever its hash ID is, literally *contains* the hash ID of earlier commit `D` (whatever *that* hash ID is).

The fact that a commit points backwards *to* its parent is what allows Git to get away with storing just *one* commit hash ID in a name like `main`.  When `main` *points to* `E`, that's sufficient, because *`E`* points to `D`.  Git can find `D` from `main` by going *through* `E`.  Since `D` points backwards to `C`, Git can find `C` from `main`, by going back two hops ... and since `C` points backwards to `B`, Git can find `B` here as well, and that finds `A` (and then we run out of commits and `git log` stops here).

> Note: `main` is protected, so a pull request is needed to apply new changes.

We now need one other fact about Git.  I mentioned above that *Git doesn't store **changes**, but rather **snapshots** called commits*, and that Git *finds* commits by starting from a branch name, then working backwards as needed.  The last thing you need to know is this: **No commit can ever be changed.**

But: if Git stores only snapshots, and no commit can ever be changed—and both of these are true—then how do we ever get any changes *into* a Git repository?  The full and correct answer is long, so [I'll take some extra time writing this up and cut it short](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2012/04/28/shorter-letter/):

- We *extract* the last commit on some branch, using the branch name.
- We then work with the *extracted* commit for a while, and eventually make a *new commit:* a new snapshot.

That is, given:

```
A--B--C--D--E   <-- main
```

we run `git checkout main` or `git switch main` to *extract* commit `E`, then we do our work, and then we run `git commit` to make a *new* commit `F`:

```
A--B--C--D--E   <-- main
             \
              F
```

In order to *find* commit `F`, we need a name—typically a branch name—so when we're using GitHub and *protected branches*, we make a *new branch name* along the way so that commit `F` is found by the new name:

```
A--B--C--D--E   <-- main
             \
              F   <-- feature
```

Then we push our own Git repository's new branch *to* GitHub, make a "pull request", and use the GitHub-specific pull request machinery to eventually incorporate either `F` or some *copy* of `F` (`F'`) on GitHub.  Again, there are a lot of details and normally I would go into all of them here, but I'm taking time to hold myself back.   If we do everything Just Right, we end up with:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F   <-- main, feature
```

and we can now delete the name `feature`.  Note that commit `F` is not changed at all.  It still points back to commit `E`.  What *has* changed is **the name `main` itself**, which now points to `F`.

This gives us a simple set of rules about Git:

- We can always add *more* commits.
- We can move branch names around.  With a GitHub "protected branch", the names **in the GitHub repositories** (but not in other clones!) are protected from being moved around.  Only some special GitHub-only cases are allowed.  *You will probably want to override this* (e.g., by temporarily de-protecting `main`), but see below.
- We *can't* change any **existing** commit.
- We can't really *delete* commits either.
- But people *find* commits using the *names*, which we can *move*.

#### On to your first problem

> Now rollback main, so it becomes:
>
> ```
> (main) 1 - 2
> ```

This would be:

```
A--B   <-- main
    \
     C--D--E
```

No *commits* have changed.  We've merely used our ability to move a *name*.  In this case we moved the name `main` to make it point to `B` instead of `E`.

This immediately runs into two problems:

1. You set `main` on GitHub to be protected.  So you have disallowed yourself from moving it yourself.
2. Even if we work around problem #1, what happens to commits `C-D-E`?

While commits `C-D-E` will stick around (for some indefinite amount of time), we only *find* commits by using a *name* and then working backwards.  We need a *name* by which we can find commit `E`.

There's a secondary problem as well, although how important it is depends on how you and your co-workers / friends / colleagues *use* Git and GitHub.  Specifically, anyone who *cloned* the *GitHub* repository probably now thinks that branch `main` should end at commit `E` too.

Git likes to *add new commits* to the end of a branch, as we saw above.  It's not very willing to "lose" commits off the end of a branch.  Git knows that if you *add* a commit to a branch—by *picking up* an all new commit like `F` that comes after `E`, or *making* an all-new commit that comes after `E`, or just taking some commit you already that, like `F`, comes after `E`, and *adding* it to `main`—if you just *add* a new commit, all the *old* commits are still there, and easy to find in Git's usual backwards fashion.  To move a branch name in such a way that it *adds* a commit, Git generally says *OK! DONE!*  (GitHub's *branch protection*, which you set up on the GitHub side in the Git repository copy that lives over on GitHub, makes it say *no* instead.)

But if you ask Git to move a branch name *backwards*, so that it will lose commits off the end of a branch, Git will generally be horrified and say *No! That would lose some commits!*  (Sure, they're still *in* there, but you would have to know the big ugly random-looking hash ID to find them.)

You can get around these:

1. To stop `main` from being protected, remove the protections: either give yourself full power (make `main` only *partly* protected), or unprotected it entirely so that everyone has full power.  Then use `git push --force` to update it so that Git's own normal *no* answer is turned into *okay, but under protest*.
2. To *keep* commits `C-D-E`, just *make a new name that remembers `E` for you*.

So once you do that, you will have:

```
A--B   <-- main
    \
     C--D--E   <-- saved
```

for instance.  After fixing up the protections on GitHub (and/or repeat as needed until the `git push --force` below works) run:

```
git switch main          # switch to main
git status               # make sure that this worked and all is clean and good
git branch saved         # make new branch name to remember E
git reset --hard HEAD~3  # force `main` back three steps
git push -f origin main  # force GitHub to drop 3 commits too
```

Whether you `git push origin saved` or not is up to you: that lets you give a name to the three commits over on GitHub's copy as well.  (Branch names are *local to each Git*.)

> Apply bug fixes as part of commits 6 and 7
>
> ```
> (main) 1 - 2 - 6 - 7
> ```

Let's draw this *properly:*

```
A--B--F--G   <-- main
    \
     C--D--E   <-- saved
```

You get to this state by, while being on `main`, creating the two new commits `F` and `G`.  Since these commits merely *add on* to `main`, you can push these directly to GitHub now (you have the ability to push directly to GitHub: `main` is not protected for *you*).  Once you've finished this step you can re-protect `main` on GitHub if you like.

#### Now for your main (no pun intended) problem

> Now merge `feature-A` back to latest state of `main`
>
> ```
> final state - (main) 1 - 2 - 6 - 7 - 3 - 4 - 5
> ```

Whoa, hold on a second: where did `feature-A` come from?

I know that you mentioned it earlier.  But *branch names* in a Git repository only matter in terms of *finding one commit*.  That one commit is the one to which the branch name points.  So where in all this was `feature-A`?  We never *drew it in*.

Before you attempt to solve *this* problem for real—and hence before you use any of what I've mentioned so far—you need to draw in `feature-A`, *properly*.  Here, you need to be careful, because when you use the GitHub protected branch feature and the merge buttons there, you can get surprises.

In particular, the green <kbd>MERGE</kbd> button has a drop-down arrow on it.  Using the arrow causes the button to change to one of three options:

- <kbd>MERGE</kbd> means just that: do a full merge.  GitHub will include a *merge commit* (see below).
- <kbd>REBASE AND MERGE</kbd> means *copy some original commits to new-and-improved ones*.  This may be what you did earlier, in which case the three `saved`-branch commits are *different commits* from the `feature-A` commits.
- <kbd>SQUASH AND MERGE</kbd> means *take a whole chain of commits, and turn them into a single ordinary commit and add that on to the end of the current branch*.  In this case `main` would not have *three* commits from some `feature-A` branch, nor a *merge commit*.  It would instead have one ordinary commit.  That doesn't fit with `C-D-E` at all.

So we've been working with a false picture.  Only *you* have the repository here, so only you can draw a *true* picture.  We cannot come to any solid conclusions without one.  However, if the picture we've been drawing here is *close enough*, this whole reset-and-rebuild method will let you proceed.  You can now simply merge `saved` with `main`:

```
git switch main    # if needed
git merge saved
```

This uses Git's merge machinery to combine work, in the usual way.

Let's redraw the inputs a bit:

```
     F-----G   <-- main (HEAD)
    /
A--B
    \
     C--D--E   <-- saved
```

This is the same drawing as before, but I've moved `F-G` up to a separate line and slid `G` over a bit.  I also added the special name `HEAD`, in parentheses, as being "attached to" `main`, so that we know which branch we are "on" when we run `git merge`.

The way merge works is to locate the best *shared* commit—a commit that's on *both branches*—as the thing that Git calls the *merge base* commit.  Here, the best shared commit, between `main` (commit `G`) and `saved` (commit `E`) is clearly commit `B`.  At least, it should be clear in the updated drawing.

So, having located commit `B` on its own, Git will now run two `git diff` commands, to see what's different in three snapshots:

- `git diff --find-renames hash-of-B hash-of-G`: this finds out what "we" changed on `main` since `B`.  That is, whatever comes out of this diff is the sum of whatever changes we made in commits `F` and `G`.
- `git diff --find-renames hash-of-B hash-of-E`: this finds out what "they" (we, really) changed on `saved` since `B`.

Git can now *combine* these two sets of changes.  This is a regular, full-blown merge, of the sort that Git tries to do on its own.  If we and they changed *different files*, or *different (non-overlapping) lines* of the same files, Git will be able to combine the changes.  Git can then apply the combined changes to the snapshot found in commit `B`.  This:

- keeps our changes, but also
- adds their changes.

The result, then, is ready to be put into a new snapshot.  The next letter is `H`, but let's call this commit `M`, and draw it in:

```
A--B--F--G---M   <-- main (HEAD)
    \       /
     C--D--E   <-- saved
```

The only thing special about commit `M` is that instead of pointing back just to commit `G`, the way an ordinary commit would, it points back to *two* commits—two *parents*, in Git's terminology—`G` and `E`.

Git*Hub* can make this commit `M` if Git can make this commit `M`.  To do that you'd just push `saved` to GitHub and issue a pull request as usual.  Note that there is no `feature-A` branch involved here: we've simply made two commits on `main`, after rolling `main` back, and then used `git merge`.  The only thing special here was the roll-back part, which required undoing branch protection and using `git push --force`.  Once commit `M` is done, we can safely delete the name `saved` because commit `E` can be found by moving to commit `M` (however we find `M`), then stepping back to the second parent.

This does also *potentially* make a small mess for anyone *else* who has a clone of the original GitHub repository.  Here's what *they* might have, in *their* Git repository:

```
A--B--C--D--E   <-- main, origin/main
             \
              H--I   <-- my-feature (HEAD)
```

If they now pick up new commits from GitHub, *their* repository becomes:

```
A--B--F--G---M   <-- origin/main
    \       /
     C--D--E   <-- main
            \
             H--I   <-- my-feature (HEAD)
```

That is, *their* `main` used to be exactly level with their `origin/main`, which said *commit `E`*.  That's *their* `main` so it has not yet changed.  If they re-synchronize their `main` right now—which will go fine as `M` is "ahead of" `E`—they will now have:

```
A--B--F--G---M   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
    \       /
     C--D--E
            \
             H--I   <-- my-feature
```

There isn't any real *problem* here, but they might want to have their `my-feature` be "based" on `origin/main` or `main`.  That is, they might *want* to *get* this now:

```
               H'-I'  <-- my-feature (HEAD)
              /
A--B--F--G---M   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
    \       /
     C--D--E
            \
             H--I   [abandoned]
```

To do that, *they* will want to use `git rebase`.  *They* will need to understand how this rebase works, in case anything goes wrong.

#### Conclusion

You may have led us all down the garden path with an improper drawing of what's actually in the repository, but if not, your specific request is pretty straightforward.  You can't do it unless and until you de-protect `main`, at least for yourself, over on GitHub, because the Git*Hub* tools will protect you from yourself here.  *Git* is perfectly willing to do this though.

Whether the minor problems this could create for *others* are something you should worry about is only something you and they can answer.

It's important to understand the mechanisms that Git uses where when looking at goals.  There are other ways to achieve various goals that don't involve `git push --force`, but without complete and accurate drawings and access to your entire team, it's hard to provide particular recommendations.

Comment: Torek: "I'm taking time to hold myself back". Also Torek: write a detailed 16900 characters long answer. Considering the limit is 30K chars, I'd say: "holding oneself back achieved".

Comment: @torek that must have been the most detailed and in-depth answer I could have ever imagined. I expected something along the lines of "run these commands and you're good to go". I apologize for the horrible illustration in my example, ha. I am just going to use your diagram as a reference in the future. As far as the question is concerned, your answer solved the issue I was facing and learnt a lot in the process. Thank you for spending your time in educating and diving into the details.